# Spring on WebLogic, how to disable Java EE

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, weblogic

It is always pain to get Spring application running on the WebLogic server without library conflicts and unexpected behavior, and the end result will be ultimately fragile to version updates anyway.

With WebLogic, is it possible to disable all the Java EE support for particular deployment expect the servlet container, i.e. pass all the control to Spring and packaged libraries without WebLogic interferencing?

Comment: We deploy Spring application to Weblogic 12 too, defining some little configuration in `weblogic.xml`. If you want, I can provide you a sample for what works for us. And finally, we define a line in Weblogic conf files, for JPA 2.1 support.

Comment: Just in case you haven't read it: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/wls/SPRNG/toc.htm